# Defining Query for OrientDB - using JSON data

Tags: orientdb

I have a question concerning using orientDB for JSON data. In my scenario, 
I receive entities which are serialized into JSON. This JSON data should
be stored in orientDB. The relevant code part to create documents 
in orientDB looks as follows:

```
//JSON string created by using Jackson
String jsonStr = "...";
//here some dummy name "test"
ODocument doc = new ODocument("test");
doc.fromJSON(jsonStr);
doc.save();
```

In the following, I give an example for classes I'm working with
(I left out constructors, getters and setters and other fields which 
are not relevant for the example):

```
class AbstractEntity { 
  private String oidString;
}
class A extends AbstractEntity {
  private List<B> bs;
}
class B extends AbstractEntity {
  private List<C> cs;
}
class C extends AbstractEntity {
  private List<D> ds;
}
class D extends AbstractEntity {
  private int type;
}
```

As the classes use type List, Jackson needs to store 
additional type information in the JSON representation, to be able 
to deserialize the data properly.

```
{
"oidString" : "AAA_oid1",
  "bs" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ {
    "oidString" : "b_oid1",
    "cs" : null
  }, {
    "oidString" : "b_oid2",
    "cs" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ {
      "oidString" : "c_oid1",
      "ds" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ ] ]
    }, {
      "oidString" : "c_oid2",
      "ds" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ {
        "oidString" : "d_oid1",
        "type" : 2
      } ] ]
    } ] ]
  } ] ]
}
```

However, I have problems querying such a document if I try to e.g. find all D instances that contain a certain type. I tried to simplify my query by first listing all D instances that can be found for a specific A:

```
OQuery<?> query = new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>(
  "select bs.cs.ds from test where oidString = 'AAA_oid1'"
);
```

This returns: {"@type":"d","@rid":"#-2:0","@version":0,"bs":[null,null]}

The additional type information ("java.util.ArrayList") seems to cause problems for orientDB. If I rewrite my example and only use ArrayList directly, hence, the additional type information is omitted, the query above shows something as a result.

Is there a general solution to this problem? I have to work with JSON data and that JSON data will contain additional type information (it has to). 
Can't deal orientDB with this situation?